# Changing Crankset on a bicycle

Tags: derailleur, gears, crankset, fixed-gear, derailleur-rear

I have a fixed gear BTwin My Bike White.

I need to upgrade but the resale value is too low for it.

So I was thinking of adding gears to it which might click the real deal for me.

Can I convert it to a 3 speed front crankset and 5 speed rear gear bicycle? (in total 15 speed bike)

Comment: Short answer is no.

Comment: And what about just adding a 5 speed rear gears?

Comment: As Batman said, no. Single speed frames do not have the correct dropout for mounting a derailleur and there are no guides for the gear cable either. You might be able to use an internally geared rear hub. Something like a Sturmey Archer S2 Kickshift hub may work depending on your rear dropout spacing. Though this only provides 2 gears.

Comment: Any adding of gears wouldn't increase the resale value once you take into account the labor and parts for doing that.

Comment: I understood the O.P. as now wanting to keep the bike, but with an upgrade to more gears so it better suits him ("click the real deal for me") as he wouldn't get much selling it on. Perhaps I have misunderstood?

Comment: Wash your bike, do the normal basic maintenance, inflate the tyres, and offer it as a tradein.   Or list it on ebay / craigslist.  No point upgrading it to sell it.

Comment: I asked 3 local professional repair guys out here in India and all of them said that this bike can only support up to a max-5 speed rear gears and it is a bit difficult to add a 3 speed front crankset.

They also said, it would cost me around $15-20. :)

Also, Decathlon also confirmed regarding the same, but they quoted $50 :)

Thank you all :)

Answer (score 3):

You've got two basic problems: namely the spacing of the rear dropouts, and the style of the dropouts. You've got a smaller problem of the *chainline*.

**If** (and only if) your frame is steel, you can [respace the frame](http://www.sheldonbrown.com/frame-spacing.html#spreading). Otherwise, you're limited to hubs that fit within the existing frame spacing. Given I assume your bike has rear facing horizontal ("track") dropouts your best bet would be an internal hub. Shimano [make/made a number of 3-speed hubs](https://web.archive.org/web/20130925001938/http://www.shimano.com/publish/content/global_cycle/en/us/index/tech_support/tech_tips.download.-Par50lparsys-0015-downloadFile.html/08%29%20Hub%20Dimensions.pdf) that fit 120mm track spacing (on hubs this is called the over-locknut distance or OLD.

Assuming the bike doesn't have cable eyelets, adding a front derailleur is much harder. You need something for the cable outer to provide a reaction force against, else the cable will have no tension. Cheaper vintage bikes used to have clamp on cable hangers, but I've not seen anything like this for sale.

Be aware that whatever you decide to do, this is potentially a very big/expensive project. You may well be better off with a second hand vintage 10-speed.

Comment: Gidday and welcome to SE Bicycles.  Excellent answer, I look forward to your future contributions.